# Arduino Flicker Timer not working

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to do Flicker (zig zag) timer where the timer interval changes after each execution. Below is my code:

```cpp
unsigned long timer;             // the timer
unsigned long interval_A = 1000; // first interval
unsigned long interval_B = 2000; // second interval
unsigned long cur_interval = 0;  // current interval
bool timer_on = false;           // flag for timer first initialization
int count = 0;                   // for alternating interval

void loop()
{
  if (!timer_on) {
    timer = millis();
    count = 1;
    cur_interval = interval_A;
    timer_on = true;
  } else {
    if ((millis() - timer) >= cur_interval) {

      if (count % 2 == 0 ){ // even
        cur_interval = interval_A;
      } else {              // odd
        cur_interval = interval_B;
      }

      timer += cur_interval;

      //do something
      Serial.println(millis(), 10);
      Serial.println(timer, 10);
      Serial.println((millis() - timer), 10);
      Serial.println("Time up !");
      Serial.println("");

      count++;  
  }
}
```

The above timer doesn't work. When ran, it will produce the following result in Serial Monitor:

```cpp
1000
2000
4294966296
Time up !

1000
4000
4294964297
Time up !
```

However if I remove the following code that is supposedly to make it alternate, it works:

```cpp
if (count % 2 == 0){ // even
  cur_interval = interval_A;
} else {             // odd
  cur_interval = interval_B;
}
```

And here is the result:

```cpp
9000
9000
0
Time up !

10000
10000
0
Time up !
```

The question is why the original code doesn't work and why it produced funny result? Any help will be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck here for a while :(

Comment: I didn't peruse your code, but `count % 0 == 0` is clearly not correct...

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It was count % 2 == 0. Result still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**
you change the value of `cur_interval` **before** this line:

```cpp
 timer += cur_interval
```

If the initial value of `timer` and `cur_interval` are respectively `5000` and `1000`, after you execute the previous instruction their values are respectively `7000` and `2000`. Since you just entered that region of code, you can expect `millis()` to return a value that is slightly greater than `5000 + 1000 = 6000`. Therefore, when you compute `millis() - timer` you get `6000 - 7000 = some large number`, because all timers are of `unsigned` type.

---

**Solution:**
move

```cpp
timer += cur_interval;
```

before you update the value of `cur_interval`, so to get *reasonable* results.

---

**Note:** instead of calling `millis()` a dozen times in your code, it would be preferable to store its returned value in a variable `cur_time` and use that instead.